# Iterating over DataFrame columns to make Matplotlib line plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I know similar questions have been posted, but nothing has worked for my particular case yet. I know it can be done with the Pandas plot function, but these lines need to be on a Matplotlib figure so they can be plotted with scatters and other things...

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lines = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABC'))
lines.columns = ['T', 'Line1', 'Line2']
lines['T'] = np.arange(0,100,0.1)
lines['Line1'] = np.cos(lines['T']) + 30
lines['Line2'] = np.sin(lines['T']) + 13
```

And I want to make a plot with 2 separate lines that share the same X axis. I can do it like this:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(lines['T'], lines['Line1'])
plt.plot(lines['T'], lines['Line2'])
plt.show()
```

Which gives me:[image]

But, I'd like to do it via loop. Sorry if this has been answered somewhere else, but I couldn't find it. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by that you want to do it with a loop?

Comment: Maybe a loop isn't the way to do it... But, I mean doing something that will iterate over the rest of the DataFrame columns, and create a new line for every column

Comment: `lines.plot(x='T')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That's a great little tip.

Comment: @QuangHoang this should be the answer. If you write it I will delete mine and upvote you

Comment: ```lines.plot(x='T',y=['Line1','Line2'])``` more explicit only if you have more columns in other cases!

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma, it seems Cody does want the rest of the columns plotted according to his comment. That's why he wants a loop - so he doesn't have to keep adding .plot calls when new columns are added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using a loop then you can do something like this:

```
for column in lines:
    if column != 'T':
        plt.plot(lines['T'], lines[column])
```

Comment: Good to hear, although I suggest @QuangHoang's comment as a better solution, it's much more simpler and readable (even though it doesn't include iteration as originally requested in your question)

Answer (score 1):

By using the `columns` property of the dataframe.

```
plt.plot(lines[lines.columns[0]], lines[lines.columns[1:]])
```

Or simply as Quang Hoang suggested in a comment:

```
lines.plot(x='T')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line_cols = ["Line1", "Line2"]

plt.figure()
for l in line_cols:
    plt.plot(lines['T'], lines[l])
plt.show()
```